# Android screen brightness that doesn't crash

Tags: android, crash, screen, brightness

I have an activity that boosts screen brightness

`/* turn screen brightness up */
this.getWindow().getAttributes().screenBrightness = 1;`

I found out this built in android function crashes some phones.

Is there a more universal way to boost screen brightness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to set attributes is with `setAttributes()`:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = this.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 1;
this.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the value that is almost `1`. For example: `0.999`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want touch events to pass through you need to do more than setting brightness.
You need to set view and layout parameters.
`view.setFocusable(false);

view.setClickable(false);

view.setKeepScreenOn(false);

view.setLongClickable(false);

view.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`

`layoutParams.height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

layoutParams.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

layoutParams.flags = 280; // You can try LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN too

layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT; // You can try different formats

layoutParams.windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Toast; // You can use only animations that the system to can access

layoutParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;

layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

layoutParams.x = 0;

layoutParams.y = 0;

layoutParams.verticalWeight = 1.0F;

layoutParams.horizontalWeight = 1.0F;

layoutParams.verticalMargin = 0.0F;

layoutParams.horizontalMargin = 0.0F;`

Take a look at my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538331/android-turn-off-display-without-triggering-sleep-lock-screen-turn-on-with-t/16034100#16034100).