# Make screen go black

Tags: android, screen

Is it possible in Android to make the screen go black? You can set the brightness to a low level but you cannot dim it until it goes black. Of course I could create an activity with just a black screen but would prefer an API that simply turns the screen off but not power down the device.

Comment: I believe turning the backlight off only dims the screen (or am I wrong?). I want it to go entirely black.

Comment: I think locking phone will do the same

Comment: Someone had a similar question and a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16034100/753632

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Turn off display without triggering sleep/lock screen - Turn on with Touchscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538331/android-turn-off-display-without-triggering-sleep-lock-screen-turn-on-with-t)